# Automating Configuration of VMware's vSwitch (OpenStack/libvirt/Nova)

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, openstack, openvswitch, vswitch

There's a lot of talk now about VMware integrating with OpenStack now.

I've noticed that Nova network service is working with VMware's standard and vDS.

Deploying a full OpenStack instance is not currently viable in our environment, but we would like to use whatever technology they are for Standard vSwitch automation. I can't find any way to do this with libvirt other than using Open vSwitch which is not ideal for our existing setups.

Currently we're controlling vSphere standard network switches using VMware's virtual machine assistant (vMA) but would like to move to a technology that is more platform independent.

So I was wondering if anyone knows what tool/API Nova is using to automate VMware's vSwitches. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What specifically needs to be automated?

Comment: Very basic stuff like setting VLANs on predefined portgroups.

Comment: I guess I'm interested in the use case here. I've managed VMware solutions at scale with distributed switches... but most of the work was manual.

Comment: Use case is an automated test environment. Resources are statically allocated via attributes in a database. Automation utility will know which port-groups are attached to each VM. Need a utility to define what those the VLANs on those port groups automatically. Yes, I know OpenStack sounds perfect for this scenario, it's a transition process, we can't do it immediately with our given infra but still want to leverage virtualization.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is if I am required to run Nicira's open vswitch to provide the functionality I want. I'm thinking that the standard and vDS provided by VMware likely don't have the right API hooks that I want other than through the vMA agent.

Comment: Possibly OpenFlow?  The Openstack source code is public, so why not try to dig through that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through PowerCLI (VMwares Powershell extension), see the following command reference;
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Set-VirtualSwitch.html